# python reading ini without key value pairs

Tags: python, configuration, ini, configparser

i am trying to read a config file which is like one showed below

```
[somesection]
value1
value2
value3
value4
[somesection2]
valuea
valueb
valuec
[somesection3]
somevalues
```

please let me know how can i read this as config parser is throwing an error :

```
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors
```

If configparser cannot parse this is there any other way ?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian why not turn your comment into an answer? More readability for passers by, a little more reputation for you

Comment: @NicolaMusatti: you can post an answer if you think it is worth it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Just posted your comment as a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2):

*(Posting @J.F.Sebastian comment as a community answer to prevent system from auto-deleting the question.)*

You need to use the optional argument `allow_no_value=True` while creating your config object.

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
```

Comment: Also remember to ping the user when you do so. (JFS in this case). Regards